# Problem connecting to private IP address

Tags: network-manager

The value of my inet addr is different for my laptop and my router, as they are on different networks i cannot proceed with sudo apt-get update. Im new to ubuntu so dont know how to use the Network manager to rectify the manner and need detailled instructions.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: yes i am connected to the internet

Answer (score 0):

Go to the right upper corner and click the network icon, go down to the bottom and right click edit connections.

This opens network connections and choose the connection to change, click edit and go to IPv4 settings.

For manual configuration

Choose Method: `Manual` and then fill in the `Address`, `Netmask` and `Gateway` ... and your desired `DNS` server.

[image]

If you router have configured `DHCP - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol` you can from manual switch to `Automatic DHCP`. Router will give you `ip`, `nm`, `gw`, `dns`